# How to read the html out of spa website with asp.net.core

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, single-page-application

As there are no API for this I need to get the HTML of the following website with WebClient response method.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.datawrapper.de/_/UPFwh/");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch(HttpRequestException e)
{
}

client.Dispose(true);
```

The problem is, when I do that I get only the source code of normal javascripts of this single page application and not the real HTML.

Anybody know how to grab the real html with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I profiled the traffic a bit and it looks like the response from that URL you're using is indeed mainly a script, which eventually will load the rest of the website.
Looking through the details the HTML part of the main data seems to be available under a different URL:

`https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/UPFwh/34/`

Consider using that instead. Hope this helps!

Comment: do u have an idea of how to get from this https://covid19info.live/

Comment: Parsing website is not the right way to query data in general. It'll be prone to issues due to any tiny changes in the UI, which are not necessarily data related. Consider finding a web API which returns the data you're looking for.

Comment: For example, I just found this by simply googling, Here they expose US data through a CSV file, which you can periodically query and parse: http://coronavirusapi.com/

Comment: coronavirusapi.com is actually cool, i have already added to my sources. I need a source, where I can get datebased CDR (Confirmed, Deaths, Recovered) numbers for countries

Comment: You'll have to look for it. I am not aware of such APIs.